# How long does ubuntu take to create ext4 journal;ing file systems for 500Gb drives?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ext4, 14.04

I have a new server with four new 500Gb rotary hard drives. I am installing Ubuntu 14.04LS from a bootable USB flash drive. I asked Ubuntu to format the HD's with ext4 journaling file systems.  Three of the hard drives have just one 500Gb partition (for data and backup) and the fourth HD has two partitions of 250Gb for OS and swap space.

The drive works well with already formatted HD's and lets me complete the installation in about 15 minutes.

However, it has been working on partition #1 of the first 500Gb HD for over five hours. Is this normal?  How long should it take to create this type of filing system on a 500Gb HD?

Comment: It could take a while but 5 hours definitely seems like too much. It could have encountered a problem with the HD.

Comment: <p>It depends on the processor of your PC.</p>
I doubt there's a precise rule for what you are asking.